# Possible to be notified when in app purchase completes?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

Am wondering, is there a way to register for a notification for when an in app purchase completes? IE either when a purchase or restore fails or succeeds? I'd like to handle these four cases so I can display an alert to the user in the view controller where the in app purchase takes place. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about implementing the "SKPaymentTransactionObserver"? It should follow the "Observer Pattern" in Objective-C to be notified when a transaction is completed (http://www.a-coding.com/2010/10/observer-pattern-in-objective-c.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(void)paymentQueue:updatedTransactions: is called when the transaction status updates.  You could show the alert windows when finishing the transactions.

```
- (void) purchaseItem:(SKProduct *) item
{
    NSLog(@"Purchasing item %@", item.localizedTitle);
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:item];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void) paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

- (void) completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *) transaction
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Transaction"
                                                message:@"Your purchase is complete"
                                                 delegate:nil
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];

    // or 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(finishTransactionSuccessfully:) name:PURCHASE_NOTE object:nil];
}
```